# How should I use stripe Payments as a Developer without signed up for Connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments

I have signed up for the Stripe account and I wanted to use this as a developer for my projects but every time I try to use it, it shows the error StripeInvalidRequestError: You can only create new accounts if you've signed up for Connect,
and my nodemon app crashes!!!

Comment: What API are you exactly trying to use? Some endpoints are for Stripe Connect (https://stripe.com/docs/connect) which is for multiparty payments. If you're only looking to accept single party payments you should start here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing some code (as text, not as screen shot) that reproduces the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests you are using the *connect* portion of the Stripe APIs. If this was intended then Stripe has some [steps to take](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide) before you can begin using it, which involves adding business details to your account.

I'm not completely familiar with the connect section of the API but Stripe offers a 'test' account mode which you may be able to utilize if you are early in the development phase and are not ready to fill out details just yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).